# Add 64 bit offset to a pointer

Tags: .net, pointers, interop, f#, native

In F#, there's the NativePtr module, but it seems to only support 32 bit offsets for its’ add/get/set functions, just like System.IntPtr does.

Is there a way to add a 64 bit offset to a native pointer (nativeptr<'a>) in F#? Of course I could convert all addresses to 64 bit integers, do normal integer operations and then convert the result again to nativeptr<'a>, but this would cost additional add and imul instructions. I really want the AGUs to perform the address calculations.

For instance, using unsafe in C# you could do something like

```
void* ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(...).ToPointer();
int64 offset = ...;
T* newAddr = (T*)ptr + offset; // T has to be an unmanaged type
```

Well actually you *can't*, because there is no "unmanaged" constraint for type parameters, but at least you can do general pointer arithmetic in a *non-generic* way.

In F# we finally got the unmanaged constraint; but how do I do the pointer arithmetic?

Comment: At first I was thinking "That's cruddy that you can't do that.", but upon rethinking it, pointer offsets only make sense if you have a contiguous allocation of memory that big. What's the use case for a contiguously allocated array greater than 4GiB?

Comment: @sblom: Imaging data can easily exceed 4 GiB ;) Of course you can partition your data etc.; but if it was possible to use larger amounts of continous allocated memory, I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this field, but I took a look at the F# implementation of the `NativePtr` module and I think that there is no performance overhead associated with converting `nativeptr<'a>` to `nativeint` and back.

The implementation uses inline IL and the inline IL code doesn't contain any code - it is there just to make the F# compiler think that the value on the stack has a different type:

```
let inline ofNativeInt (x:nativeint)    = (# "" x : nativeptr<_> #)
let inline toNativeInt (x:nativeptr<_>) = (# "" x : nativeint    #)
```

In fact, the `NativePtr.add` method also uses these two methods - it converts the pointer to `nativeint` and then adds the 32bit integer (multiplied by the size of the `'a` type).

So, the following function should be fine:

```
let inline addNativeInt (x:nativeptr<'a>) (n:nativeint) : nativeptr<'a> = 
   (NativePtr.toNativeInt x) + n |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt
```

All functions used in the code should be inlined, so you'll end up with just a single instruction for addition (though, I have not verified that). You don't even have to worry about using the function multiple times in your code (you can work with `nativeptr<'a>` all the time and use this function for addition).

However, partitioning data may also be an option - as far as I know, the MSR team that was using F# for processing some large (>2GB) data sets used exactly this approach - they partitioned the data into 2GB blocks (stored in arrays).

Comment: +1 very interesting, thanks. I also tried to look into NativePtr, but at least Reflector only shows "// This item is obfuscated and can not be translated".

Comment: @Novox: You can download version of F# for Visual Studio 2008 - it ships with the source code (in the `source` directory). That's a very useful source of information :-). Funny that Reflector cannot cope with the code!

Answer (score 1):

> Imaging data can easily exceed 4 GiB
>   ;)

It can't, x64 code has a +/-2 GB offset restriction.  One of the reasons you can't allocate arrays larger than 2GB in .NET.  This restriction exists in unmanaged 64-bit C/C++ code as well.  There are libraries that work around this restriction, like WIC, but addressing *all* of the bitmap bits directly doesn't make sense when you use them.

Nevertheless, it is possible to generate such an address by casting IntPtr to long in C#:

```
IntPtr addr = SomeCall();
long offset = blah;
addr = (IntPtr)((long)addr + offset);
```

Comment: First: As I said in my question, I don't want to cast to long, I want to use the AGUs for pointer arithmetic.
Second: AllocHGlobal (GlobalAlloc in Win32) happily allocates >2 GiB on x64. So what's that "+/-2 GB offset restriction"?

Comment: It's not an allocation restriction, it is an addressing restriction.  Keep this thread moving by showing exactly why you need to address more than 2 GB.  AGU is another obscure 3 letter acronym to me.

Comment: AGU is the _A_ddress _G_eneration _U_nit of a CPU. Do you have a reference for that offset restriction? Why I need this? Well if you use a HPC cluster with 32 GiB RAM per compute node, you want to make use of it, right? FEM stiffness matrices can get quite large for complex models, even though they are sparse. Even more so for CFD simulations with millions of finite volume cells. Or think of applications like coherence-enhancing diffusion image filtering of MRT images and the like.

Comment: Btw.: What exactly is supposed to happen when you run into this offset restriction? I implemented a minimalistic 64-bit native array using the trick suggested by Tomas and it *seems* to work so far.